# Showing ImageView in a horizontal RecyclerView places large margins around(?) the image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-recyclerview

I'm building an Android Application where the user can take photos at a click of a button, and this photos are shown on the same activity. The photos are inside a RecyclerView and the RecyclerView's Orientation is horizontal. I can take photos, save them, and rotate them as needed. I can also show them to the user via the RecyclerView so that it appears to be an Image Gallery.

However, it seems that the individual LinearLayout containing the ImageView takes up a whole lot more of space than what the ImageView needs.

Here's a screenshot of the activity without any photos yet. I placed a white background for the RecyclerView:

[image: Blank RecyclerView]

After taking a photo using the camera, I manage to get the photo, rotate it (because when the camera is in portrait, Android sometimes saves it as landscape), and display it. The RecyclerView Adapter's Layout has a black background and an imageView on top. Here's the layout I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I set the ImageView's bitmap gets set (in the RecyclerView Adapter) with the file path as the source, this happens:

[image: RecyclerView with Image]

As you can see, I have my ImageView. However, it seems that the LinearLayout parent of the ImageView does NOT wrap the ImageView. Instead of the white background that the RecyclerView had, the black background of the LinearLayout is the one that's showed. And yes, this takes up the entire RecyclerView.

I don't know why the linearLayout isn't wrapping the ImageView as it should. I've also tried different scaleTypes for the ImageView but it does not show optimal results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView`.